# MySQL 8.0.18 all privileges on a database for role doesn't allow user to create the database

Tags: mysql, authorization

I use roles to give grants to my MySQL users. I noticed a strange behavior which I couldn't find documented anywhere when granting roles to users. Let me walk you through it.

First we create an actual user `joe`@`localhost` and grant it *all* privileges on `joe_db`. While I omit the second step in my code, I use it here to illustrate how unexpected this behavior is. (`$ mysql` logs me in as root).

```
$ mysql
mysql> CREATE USER 'joe'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
mysql> ALTER USER 'joe'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '1234';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
mysql> GRANT ALL ON `joe_db`.* TO 'joe'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.02 sec)
mysql> exit
Bye
```

Now for the sake of eliminating other issues I log in as `joe`@`localhost` and assert that my grants indeed work.

```
$ mysql -ujoe -p1234 -hlocalhost
mysql> CREATE DATABASE `joe_db`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
mysql> DROP DATABASE `joe_db`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
mysql> exit
Bye
```

Now let's login as root again and create a new role `joe_role`. We grant the very same privileges to this role as we do on `joe`@`localhost`. Then we grant `joe_role` to `joe`.

```
$ mysql
mysql> CREATE ROLE 'joe_role';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
mysql> GRANT ALL ON `joe_db`.* TO `joe_role`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
mysql> GRANT `joe_role` TO `joe`@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
mysql> exit
Bye
```

Let's login as `joe` again and activate the `joe_role`. Doing this will prevent us from creating a database. This behavior is what I question. **Is this expected? Is there a way to create a role for user which has a privilege to create `joe_db` without granting global permissions?**

```
$ mysql -ujoe -p1234 -hlocalhost
mysql> SET ROLE `joe_role`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> CREATE DATABASE `joe_db`;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'joe'@'localhost' to database 'joe_db'
```

For the sake of eliminating other issues, let's see what happens when we set `joe` privileges to global.

```
mysql> exit
Bye
$ mysql
mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* to `joe_role`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
mysql> exit
Bye
$ mysql -ujoe -p1234 -hlocalhost
mysql> CREATE DATABASE `joe_db`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

It works again. Revoking the role makes it work again too. Neither is obviously a solution.

To summarize:
What am I doing wrong or how did I misunderstand the concept of roles that this is happening?

I use [this MySQL 8.0.18 image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/mysql/library/mysql/8.0.18/images/sha256-119ecffb345e201c406e12e203b550aece0dc34671fe19069f00f1825f8d6b98?context=explore).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A role with the same grants as the user, when assigned to the user, prevents them from creating database. This doesn't happen with global grants (`*.*`) on the user or the role, neither with `SELECT` privileges on database. Only `CREATE` privileges exhibit this behavior. According to [this thread](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=98876) this is an expected behavior.

EDIT: This was confirmed to be a bug and is fixed in 8.0.22.